# Android-Job run every time device is plugged in

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-job

In my Android app I need to run a background service every time the device is plugged in and idle (it should start after the user connects his device to the charger and end when he disconnects it).

What I want is a similar thing to listening for the ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED broadcast, but targeting Oreo this broadcast doesn't get sent.

I tried Android-Job from Evernote because it doesn't require Google Play Services, as Firebase JobDispatcher does.

```
 new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
```

The problem is that I don't want to have to schedule the job every time. Instead, I want to schedule the job once and have it run every time the user connects his device to the charger.

How can it be done?
Thank you.

Comment: Do this work fine when ever you plug in the device,as I face the issue whenever I plug the Job doesnt start.I have only one condition thats the device should be charging.i.e ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED just.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's fine for me to run the job only once a day, but only when the device is plugged in, I have solved the problem like this:

```
public class ProcessPhotosJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "process_photos_job";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        new ProcessPhotos().execute(getContext());
        scheduleForTomorrow();
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static void scheduleNow() {
        schedule(1);
    }

    public static void scheduleForTomorrow() {
        schedule(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    }

    private static void schedule(long delayMillis) {
        if (!JobManager.instance().getAllJobRequestsForTag(TAG).isEmpty()) {
            // Job already scheduled
            return;
        }

        new JobRequest.Builder(ProcessPhotosJob.TAG)
            .setExecutionWindow(delayMillis, delayMillis + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
            .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.